# mac os 10.5.8 can support any version of xcode that supports iphone os 4.0?

Tags: xcode

Hi i have an mac os 10.5.8

i am trying to port my project which runs on  xcode version 3.2.4 fine

my current xcode version on the mac 10.5.8 is version 3.0

it gives me an graphic assertion error.

so i am guessing its a problem with the version

Answer (score 2):

The version of Xcode and Simulator which is compatible with the iOS 4.x SDK requires Snow Leopard (OS 10.6.x).

Comment: in that case will be able to port my project from 3.2.4 to xcode 3.0?

Comment: sorry just to add the app is target to support version 3.0 minimum